# Java.lang.numberformatexception: Invalid float "0.008466"

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I'm just getting 0.008466 value from a php request, and convert it to float but can't get it.

I've tried to use numberFormat and DecimalFormat and Float.parseFloat but nothing working...

```
private void retrieveMinuteByDegreeValueFromPhp() throws IOException {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(URL_PHP_MINUTEDEGREE);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    if ( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
        String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        float minuteByDegree = Float.valueOf(str);
        if (minuteByDegree > 0){
            editor.putFloat(MINUTEBYDEGREE, minuteByDegree);
            editor.commit();
        }
        Log.d("MinuteByDegree","Minutebydegree : " + minuteByDegree);

    }
    else {
        Log.d("MinuteByDegee","Error : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Well if the dot is the issue then replacing it by itself won't do anything to solve it.

Comment: That comes from a php code so probably another encoding so replacing a weird dot by a decimal dot should fix it.

Comment: If you don't use the "weird dot" as input to the replace method it won't get replaced, i.e. you'd actually have to know what kind of "weird dot" to expect. If you use the string literal `"."` it will always be the _same_ character.

Comment: Btw, did you verify that the string value is only `0.008466`?

Comment: I thing that it's the dot because others are just digits. And parsing 8466 works so why 0.08466 don't ?

Comment: assertThat(Float.valueOf("0.008466"), is(0.008466f));
yields a pass. You need to inspect the string and isolate what the characters involved are

Comment: @Thomas yes I've put it in the log

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and check each character. None of the character values should be above 57 (the ascii value for the digit 9).

Comment: @Thomas : Thank you very much, finally I've used str.toCharArray and the first character was \uEEF so I've removed it and now that work. I could not see it inside String but only in the array ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Thomas, there were a bad character hidden in string but not the the char Array. :)